# Localhost Sites not loading CSS JS etc Mac

Tags: wordpress, macos, .htaccess, localhost

After upgrading to High Sierra, my localhost no longer worked. After following a ton of tutorials and spending a lot of time I got it to work. However my Wordpress sites are not loading the CSS or Javascript Files. I think maybe that the links to them are somehow broken. I had to change a lot in the http.conf file. Perhaps I changed some rewrite rules by accident. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried looking in the `network-tab` of the element-inspector and then refreshing the page to see where the site is loading the files from? Changing the http.conf file could definitely cause that. What are you using to build locally? Vagrant? Docker?

Comment: I just use Wordpress running off the inbuilt MySQL server. Yes the element-inspector shows that it is trying to load the files from the localhost folder but it says that they have failed to load. eg: localhost/~paul/Site-Name/wp-content/filename.js .. **Penny just dropped. The address bar says localhost/Site-Name but the files are trying to be loaded from localhost/~paul/Site-Name so I must have messed up the configuration somehow.. Hopefully somebody can help. Thanks

Comment: I'm going to write a new question based on this revelation :-)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48113282/localhost-wordpress-sites-not-loading-css-after-apache-setup-mac