# LocalHost Wordpress sites not loading css after Apache Setup Mac

Tags: wordpress, apache, localhost, httpd.conf

After Upgrading to High Sierra my localhost no longer worked. I followed a number of tutorials and finally got it to work but now my Wordpress sites load but do not load the CSS and Javascript files. When I check inspector it shows that it can not load the files because the directory is wrong. The address bar says localhost/Site-Name but the files are trying to be loaded from localhost/~paul/Site-Name so I must have messed up the configuration somehow.. Hopefully somebody can help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround which while it does not fix my localhost not showing the Sites folder at localhost/~paul it does allow my Wordpress sites to work. I created a folder within my sites folder called ~paul and then moved all my sites into that. Now the CSS JS etc all load fine and I am happy with that.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling your css file in the `header.php` like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>[path to your css from project root]/your-css.css">
```

I had a similar problem and using `get_template_directory_uri()` allowed me to solve the it because in that case, the path given in Wordpress gets the files from the root directory.

What happens if you `echo` this `get_template_directory_uri()` , it's supposed to show you the template dir something like:

```
localhost/wp-content/themes/[your theme]
```

Comment: Mind explaining why?

Comment: @jwaw I'm sorry, I am asking for an Apache configuration solution not a Wordpress solution.

Comment: @DarkCygnus, actually i had a similar problem and using get_template_directory_uri(); allowed me to solve the problem because in that case, the path given in wordpress gets the files from the root directory.  what happens if you echo this 'get_template_directory_uri();' that was my main point, it's supposed to show you the template dir something like that : http://localhost/wp-content/themes/[your theme].  Good luck

Comment: @jwaw thanks for clarifying. Would you mind including that to your answer? Comments can be deleted without warning and that valuable information can be lost.

Comment: @DarkCygnus, thank you for the information. i've included it to my original answer. hope it helps a bit

Comment: @jwaw it did :) I suggested some edit to improve its appearance.